# Getting compile error while implementing a simple Generic methods in java

Tags: java, generics

Getting compile error while implementing a Generic methods in java

*My Generic interface :*

```
interface GenericInterface {
    <T> T genericMethod(T t);
}
```

*Below is my implementation which is throwing error:*

```
public class GenericImplementation implements GenericInterface {

    // Not working
    @Override
    public Double genericMethod(Double t) {
        System.out.println("Trying to implement generic method with return T and method args T as well ");
        return t*4.3;
    }

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciate in advance, I am missing something in Generic class implementation might be.

Comment: Your interface is not generic. Only the method in it is generic.

Comment: Also, post the error the compiler is giving.That is precious information needed to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want your implementation to be for a specific type, the type variable has to be declared on the class/interface:

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
    T genericMethod(T t);
}
```

and implement like:

```
public class GenericImplementation implements GenericInterface<Double> {
```

`<T> T genericMethod(T t)` doesn't mean an implementation can be for any type, it means it has to be for *all* types. You can't restrict it to one type.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and brief details, it help me a lot.